# How to Move Vertices Symmetrically Without Scale

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, geometry

Is there a way to move vertices away from each other without using scale?

I have two groups of vertices that I want to move away from each other the same distance in both directions.  I know that I can grab them all and then scale away from the pivot point, but the problem is that it distorts the groups.

Before Scale:
[image]

After Scale:
[image]

How can I do this without scale, and without having to move the groups individually?

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting *Vertices* not *Edges* before scaling ? Can you share the blend file ? I ll give it a try

Comment: Hello, Glen, it would be great if you could share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ for @Tune. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Tune thanks for your offer, I appreciate it, but Robin nailed it for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This move is a relative translation, not a scale. For a symmetrical object like this one, you could either work under a *Mirror* modifier, or use the 'Mesh Symmetry' setting in the header:

[image]

In this orientation, the operation is <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Robin thank you for this. I've tried using the Mesh Symmetry option so many times and it never worked (no idea why) so I thought it must be for something else beyond my understanding.  Now in this instance it is working exactly how I always figured it should, but prior to your post I had abandoned all hope of using it.  So thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for ;)